# C++ assert a method is streamable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have this piece of code to create a string representation for an object.

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string streamable_to_s(const T& obj)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << obj;
    return ss.str();
}


template <typename T>
std::string non_streamable_to_s(const T& obj)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << &obj;

    std::string type_name = typeid(obj).name();
    std::string addr = ss.str();

    return "<" + type_name + " " + addr + ">";
}


template <typename T>
std::string to_s(const T& obj)
{
    return is_streamable<T>()
        ? streamable_to_s(obj)
        : non_streamable_to_s(obj);
}
```

And this is my function to check whether a type is streamable:

```cpp
template<typename S, typename T>
class _streamable
{
    template<typename SS, typename TT>
    static auto test(int)
    -> decltype(std::declval<SS&>() << std::declval<TT>(), std::true_type());

    template<typename, typename>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

public:
    static const bool value = decltype(test<S, T>(0))::value;
};


template <typename T>
bool is_streamable()
{
    return _streamable<std::stringstream, T>::value;
}
```

This code runs fine when I use it on an instance of a streamable type.

However, the compiler still complains when I use `to_s` and pass in an instance of a type where `<<` operator is not implemented.

Is there any way that I can assert int `to_s` that when I call `streamable_to_s`, the instance that I passed in already has `<<` operator implemented? Or is there any way that I can suppress the error generated by the compiler?

Comment: What is the error message you're receiving?

Comment: I imagine if you replace the ternary with `if constexpr` it'll work